# MVC Where To Put View Component Files

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor

A question about project structure. So far I have 3 ViewComponents in a .NET Core app.

In the Microsoft page about View Components, they use the namespace ViewComponentSample.ViewComponents, but in practice, the engine searches for View Components in

- /Pages/Components/ProductBox/Default.cshtml
- /Pages/Shared/Components/ProductBox/Default.cshtml
- /Views/Shared/Components/ProductBox/Default.cshtml

Which means: Creating a ViewComponents folder next to Pages/Views/Models won't work as it won't find them.

So that means I place them in Pages/Shared, correct? While partial views start with "_", should I leave that out for ViewComponents?

Currently I've put it in Pages\Shared\ProductBox, with the view in Pages\Shared\Components\ProductBox\Default.

Then remains 2 more issues. Namespace and location of model.

This ProductBox should be in namespace MyWebsite.Pages.Shared, or in namespace MyWebsite.ViewComponents ?

As for the model, should I place it in the Models folder or next to the View Component, as it's code directly related to it? I don't like spreading the component into 3 folders (ViewComponent, Components\ProductBox and Models). It does feel a bit strange to have ProductBox there but it's just like pages having their models next to them.

And for the model associated to the View Component, so far I have 3 components using their models completely differently.

- LatestArticlesViewComponent: has RssItem class defined as a subclass and it returns a list of them.
- CoachingFormViewComponent: model derives form PageModel and the ViewComponent does nothing else than pass the page's model to the View.
- ProductBoxViewComponent: model is a POCO class initiated by the ViewComponent with display properties.

(at first I was passing the ViewComponent class as the model for the view but this was a code smell so I changed it to use a separate model class)

Am I doing it right? I've done progress but want to make sure I'm on the right track.

Answer (score 5):

Frankly, none of this matters. You can put anything wherever you want. The views for the components, by convention should go in `{Views,Pages}/Shared/Components`. The `Views`/`Pages` part of the path is merely dependent on whether you're using Razor Pages or MVC views, and even then, it's only so you don't need an additional folder. With Razor Pages, by default, there's no `Views` folder, and likewise with MVC, by default, there's no `Pages` folder. However, you can use both Razor Pages and MVC in the same project, and therefore could theoretically have both directories. In which case, where you put your components is entirely a judgement call. However, all this aside, you can alter these conventions or directly reference views from your component. In either case, then, the component views could go wherever you choose. It's entirely up to you.

The actual view components themselves are largely the same. The convention is to put them in in a folder call `ViewComponents`, but that's entirely optional. ASP.NET Core pulls them in via reflection, so the actual location doesn't really matter at all, nor the namespace. Namespaces are even more intangible, as they don't matter literally at all here. You could follow the convention of where the file is located, or use something else entirely.